# WinForms - MVP - Forms Events in Form Interface

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to implement MVP in a small WinForms App I am developing.

As known, I need to define an `IView` interface.

The `IView` interface should have an event that is fired when the concrete `View` loads.

This event is already implented in WinForms as the `Load()` event.

Now in some guides/tutorials I have seen they implemented it like this

```
Public Interface IView
    Event OnPrepareView()
    .....
End Interface

Public Class MainForm
Inherits Form
Implements IView

    Private Sub Main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        RaiseEvent OnPrepareView()
    End Sub

    Public Event OnPrepareView()

End Class
```

Now I was wondering if its possible to expose directly the Form `Load` event directly in the interface, so that `IView` looks like:

```
Public Interface IView
    Event Load()
    .....
End Interface
```

And the Load event is implemented in the Form with it's `load` event.

If possible how should I do it in VB?

**UPDATE**

For example for a Property like `Icon`or Function like `Show` which are defined in `System.Windows.Forms.Form`.

I would have an `IView`:

```
Public Interface IView
    Property Icon as Icon
    Sub Show()
End Interface
```

And then in my concrete implementation

```
Public Class FooForm
Inherits Form
Implements IView

    Public Overloads Property Icon as Icon Implementes IView.Icon
    Get
        return MyBase.Icon
    End Get
    Set
        MyBase.Icon = value
    End Set

    Public Overloads Sub Show()
        MyBase.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

but how can I do for the Form events?

Or should I just declare new Event in `IView` like:

```
Public Interface IView
    Property Icon as Icon
    Sub Show()
    Event OnLoad()
End Interface

Public Class FooForm
Inherits Form
Implements IView
....
....
    Public Event OnLoad() Implements IView.OnLoad

    Private Sub FooForm_Load() Handles Me.Load
        RaiseEvent OnLoad()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Try adding Inherits Form Implements IView

Comment: I forgot it in the code but it already like you said....after reading for long I think Vb.Net can't handle this. I think I need to overload the method/property/event and then call the base method/class/whatever from the base class like said here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607884/vb-net-class-inherits-a-base-class-and-implements-an-interface-issue-works-in-c

Comment: The event should be declared in Interface and should be Implemented in the form and raised it in `OnLoad` event of the `Form`. Like what you did for the first event.

Comment: @RezaAghaei small example would be possible? I just want to know, if its possible in VB to use the form events (like load, closed, closing etc) as implementations of an interface that defines an event with the same signature. In other words, if I can expose the form events through an interface... In C# this is no problem, but in VB I have to use "Implements Ifoo.Foo". But I can write this in VB, since the events are declared in a base class (in the case of a WinForm, are declared in System.Windows.Forms.Form)

Comment: I updated my question with a detailed example. So if I understand you right, should my IView interface declare new events, which are raised by the form on the event handlers of the correct event. For ex. IView has new Event "OnLoad" and it will be raised in Sub Form_Load() Handles Form.Load?

Comment: Yes, just instead of handling the `Load` event in form, you can override `OnLoad` method which is responsible to raise `Load` event.

Comment: But is there such a method for all events in forms? If not, is my way the way I should do it, by defining new events and raising it when the proper form events fires? If you write an answer, with your comment solution and answeing this I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare the event in the interface, then in the `Form` implement the interface, then override `OnLoad` and raise the event. For example:

```
Public Interface IView
    Event Load As EventHandler
End Interface

Public Class Form1
    Implements IView
    Public Shadows Event Load As EventHandler Implements IView.Load
    Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnLoad(e)
        RaiseEvent Load(Me, e)
    End Sub
End Class
```